# What will happen if one of the guardians (cloud, sun, rain etc.) dies?

Tags: reborn

What would happen if one of the guardians died in a fight with another mafia family? For example: the vongola rain guardian of the 8th generation dies and everyone else is still alive..

Would the family/the boss just search a new one and replace him? Or would the place stay "free" until the next generation of guardians/bosses will selected? if that's the case: would be the boss (of the vongola family for example) stay alone if all guardians die? or will he just select new ones and stay as the boss?

Comment: Very interesting question.